# How do I deal with neighbors palm tree hanging over my driveway/ cars, when it seems to leak or drop a sappy substance.

Tags: tree-care, palm

My neighbors palm tree is located next to my driveway where we park our cars. For many years ,About 2 or 3 times a year the tree seems to drop a mist of sappy substance that sprays all over our cars. It seems to be water solvable because it does come off at the car wash. How do I get my neighbor to spray the tree to stop the sap from falling or is there nothing that can be done??

Comment: it could be two things either a pest problem like aphids pooing their sticky sugary stuff- or it might be the variety of palm- in which a photo both close up of the foliage and several feet away to gage size of palm might be useful to further extra  answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing short of hacking the palm down.  You could easily cover your cars with a light, inexpensive fabric to catch the 'honey dew'.  Please send pictures.  Legally there is nothing at all you can do...make nice with the neighbors.  They aren't having the problems you are having so the only recourse to entice them is to have another species of tree not so amenable to aphids and other sap sucking insects that are pooping on your driveway...costly.

Comment: Legally you can probably cut it on the property line, where it hangs over. May not do much for neighborly relations, but their right to grow a plant stops at the property line, pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Nope, I've been in court and this is where it gets very weird.  You can't chop up a plant that is your neighbor's if it will weaken or kill it.  Or even aesthetically ruin it.  Different laws everywhere surely but to piss off your neighbors is far worse than gummy cars.  Even digging the roots out of the soil!  Making nice with the neighbors enhances one's home in a big way.  Making enemies means home doesn't feel safe anymore.